# comparing $var to

Tags: bash, if-statement, var

I have a test script the needs to read the variable 'LAB' and e-mail the correct company.
I've looked but can't find anything that has worked yet.

Any thoughts?

```
#!
#
LAB=3
#
if [ "$LAB" = "$1" ];then
    echo "Got Zumbrota" && ./mailZ 
fi
#
if [ "$LAB" = "$2" ];then
    echo "Got Barron" && ./mailB 
fi
#
if [ "$LAB" = "$3" ];then
    echo "Got Stearns" && ./mailS
fi
```

Comment: change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash -x` and look at the output. If you are comparing numbers, read through [this page](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)

Comment: `"$3"` is the third argument passed to your script "3" is the value 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this a bash script, start your file with

```
#!/bin/bash
```

and use `-eq` for integer comparison and since LAB is an integer in your script

```
if [ $LAB -eq $1 ]
```

Comment: `$1` is not the value `1`, instead its the first argument to the function/script. Use `[ $LAB  -eq 1 ]`. AND its better to use the builtin `[[` than `[`. i.e. `if [[ $LAB -eq 1 ]]`

Comment: At least in newer versions of bash, `test, [...] and [[...]]` are all builtins.

Comment: @William: True, but `test` and `[` have to be compatible with their non-builtin versions, so they have some stupid behaviors. `[[` is not just builtin but actually *special*, so it . . . well, it also has some stupid behaviors, but not quite as many.

Comment: @ruakh: [[...]] is also faster, generally, but builtin isn't the deciding factor it once was. (Using case...esac where appropriate is still faster than all of them, and very portable.)

Answer (score 1):

These cascading if statements can be condensed into a case statement:

```
case "$LAB" in
1)  echo "Got Zumbrota" && ./mailZ 
    ;;
2)  echo "Got Barron" && ./mailB 
    ;;
3)  echo "Got Stearns" && ./mailS
    ;;
*)  echo "don't know what to do with $LAB"
    ;;
esac
```